# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform not present

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

From where do i obtain the dll Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform. I installed the Identitymodel activedirectory package from nugget but it doesn't contain the definition for the dll in question. I am using the VS 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PM > Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

For more refer
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: This package no longer contains that DLL, and hasn't for a while.